# Finalizing adapter's view holders once adapter no longer in use

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview

Consider the following scenario

- Fragment (used for example as a page in swipe layout) uses a RecyclerView
- That RecyclerView's adapter creates viewholders that register themselves as observers on an Observable.
- The Observable is a singleton that shares the application's lifecycle not the fragment's

The problem is, when the fragment is stopped (I assume at this point adapter's `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` is called and it along with the recyclerview are garbage collected) The view holders will not since the Observable still has reference to them, thus causing a memory leak. My question is how does one do that?

Disclaimer, the following paragraph is what I thought the solution could be at first but failed, my question is not how to get that solution to work as that could be an XY problem.

So I need to find a way to call `observable.deleteObserver(this)` from each viewholder. I assumed I can do so from `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` The problem I ran into is how to iterate over all view holders.

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>Sorry for the mess in the title, I am bad at naming things :(</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: afaik `RecyclerView` does not hold a list of all created view holders: you have to do it by yourself

Comment: why are you attaching observer to each and every view holder ?. simply have one observer for your adapter or fragment and update your list based on data received on update() method.